# Select a table using criteria taken from another table

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables, the one called m_loan and the another one called m_action. I want to select datas from m_loan with criteria taken from the m_action

Here are the tables structure.
**m_loan**

no 
name 
accno 
par 
frequency

**m_action**
no
par
freq_min
freq_max
action

for example if there is a criteria data in m_action 
1, 1, 3, 4, confiscation of collateral
2, 1, 1, 2, call the creditor

and there are some data in m_loan 
1, Joko, 12345, 1, 2

the data above (Joko) will get the "call the creditor" respond because the PAR is 1 and the frequency is 2 (in the range of the 'call the creditor').

I have no idea how to to this. Thank you for your kind respond:)

Comment: Is the 'no' column common to the two tables?  In other words, can we join the two tables on that column?  Or perhaps 'par' is common?

Comment: I didn't down-vote this because you are a new user and I want to give you a chance, but we are going to need a lot more information here before anyone will be able to help you.  For instance how are the tables related, what do 'no' and 'par' mean, and how many people are going to get their cars repo'd if you get this thing working? (just kidding)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, no is the primary key (the id). I wanna classify each record of m_loan based on the par and freq_min and freq_max inserted in the m_action

Comment: ...but is 'no' the same in both tables for related rows, in other words, an id key in one and a look-up (foreign key relationship) in the other, or is is two separate id keys (1 for each table) that have no relationship to each other?

Comment: And btw par stands for Portofolio at Risk in bank accountancy

Comment: the id of each table is different

Comment: So how do we know which rows in one table correspond to rows in the other?

Comment: ...and when you say 'id' do you mean the column called 'no'?

Answer (score 0):

Following sql will be helpful to you,

```
select ml.*, ma.action from m_loan ml, m_action ma 
where ml.par = ma.par and (ml.frequency between ma.freq_min and ma.freq_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from m_loan where m_loan.par=m_action.par and (m_loan.frequency between m_action.freq_min and m_action.freq_max)